# Is there a guarantee that onchange will run earlier than an event added to the tag?

Tags: javascript

I am generating a tag from server-side:

```
'<select class="form-data api command" data-command-name="GetDifficultyData" data-events="change" name="id" data-data="" onchange="this.attributes[\'data-data\']=\'data=\' + this.value">'.$difficultyOptions.'</select>'
```

I am using PHP to do so, but it is not very relevant for this question.

But I have a `function` which will add an `event` to my `select` tag because it is marked to handle a `command`:

```
function initializeCommands(root) {
    if (!root) root = document;
    if (!radWindow) {
        radWindow = document.getElementById("radwindow");
        var closeRadWindow = function(event) {
            radWindow.addClass("hide-popup");
        };
        radWindow.addEventListener("click", closeRadWindow);
        var popupActionContainer = radWindow.querySelector(".popup-action-container");
        popupActionContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            if (!event) {
                event = window.event;
            }
            event.cancelBubble = true;
            if (event.stopPropagation) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            return false;            
        });
        popupActionContainer.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
            if ((e.code == 'Enter') && (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "textarea")) {
                var mainButton = this.querySelector("span.api[data-form-name]");
                mainButton ? mainButton.click() : closeRadWindow();
            }
        });
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
            if (e.code == 'Escape') {
                closeRadWindow();
            }
        });
        popupActionContainer.querySelector(".icon-close").addEventListener("click", closeRadWindow);
    }
    if (!popupContent) {
        popupContent = radWindow.querySelector("#popup-content");
    }
    var commandButtons = root.querySelectorAll(".api:not(.initialized)");
    for (var commandIndex = 0; commandIndex < commandButtons.length; commandIndex++) {
        var eventsToHandle = commandButtons[commandIndex].attributes["data-events"].value.split(" ");
        for (var eventIndex = 0; eventIndex < eventsToHandle.length; eventIndex++) {
            commandButtons[commandIndex].addEventListener(eventsToHandle[eventIndex], function(event) {
                if (this.hasClass("confirm")) {
                    if (!confirm(this.hasAttribute("data-confirm-message") ? this.attributes["data-confirm-message"].value : "Biztos ebben?")) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (this.hasClass("template")) {
                    var data = this.attributes["data-data"];
                    sendRequest("POST", "/template/" + this.attributes["data-template-name"].value, templateCallback, true, (data ? data.value : data));
                } else if (this.hasClass("form")) {
                    var container = document.querySelector(this.attributes["data-container"].value);
                    var items = container.querySelectorAll(".form-data");
                    var data = [];
                    var props = [];
                    for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
                        var v = items[index].value;
                        if (items[index].tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
                            if (items[index].type === "checkbox") {
                                v = items[index].checked;
                            }
                        }
                        data.push(items[index].name + "=" + v);
                        props.push(items[index].name);
                    }
                    var recaptchaResponse = container.querySelectorAll("[name=g-recaptcha-response]");
                    if (recaptchaResponse.length > 0) {
                        data.push("g-recaptcha-response=" + recaptchaResponse[0].value);
                        props.push("g-recaptcha-response");
                    }
                    var errorPlaces = container.querySelectorAll('.error-text:not(.invisible)');
                    for (var errorIndex = 0; errorIndex < errorPlaces.length; errorIndex++) {
                        errorPlaces[errorIndex].addClass("invisible");
                    }
                    var validationResults = validate(items);
                    if (validationResults.length) {
                        for (var errorIndex = 0; errorIndex < validationResults.length; errorIndex++) {
                            var errorPlace = container.querySelector('.error-text[data-key="' + validationResults[errorIndex].key + '"]');
                            if (errorPlace) {
                                errorPlace.removeClass("invisible").innerText = validationResults[errorIndex].value;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        sendRequest("POST", "/form/" + this.attributes["data-form-name"].value, function() {
                            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                                var r = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                                for (var key in r) {
                                    if (r[key] && (props.indexOf(key) >= 0)) {
                                        var errorPlace = container.querySelector('.error-text[data-key="' + key + '"]');
                                        if (errorPlace) {
                                            errorPlace.removeClass("invisible").innerText = r[key];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                eval(r.response);
                            }
                        }, true, data.join("&"));
                    }
                } else if (this.hasClass("command")) {
                    var data = this.attributes["data-data"];
                    sendRequest("POST", "/command/" + this.attributes["data-command-name"].value, function() {
                        if (this.readyState === 4) {
                            var r = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                            if (r.callback) {
                                eval(r.callback);
                            }
                        }
                    }, true, ((data && data.value) ? data.value : data));
                }
            });
        }
        commandButtons[commandIndex].addClass("initialized");
    }
}
```

This `function` runs on page load and also in some cases when popup window content is generated through the API (my current case is with a popup window). To sum the situation up:

- page loads
- the user clicks on a button
- a request is sent to the server
- the server responds with popup content, including the tag I have shown at the start of this question and the `onchange` is defined on server-side and therefore will be valid from the start of the life cycle of the tag
- a popup callback is being executed and the tag will have an event handler for `change`

The importance of the order of execution is that the `onchange` should be executed *before* the event later added to the tag, since the event will send the `id` of the select tag to the server (so it will ask data regarding the entity to be edited) and it is important to send the current `id`. My current tests work well, `onchange` is being executed before the `change` event which was later added to the tag and everything is fine. However, I am worried about some browsers or future versions where this might not happen in the same way. In that case I would need to do some further work to guarantee that the `onchange` is executed first and only then the `change` event. I could do that work anyway, but I would like to keep the code elegant and to avoid writing unnecessary code. So, the question is: is it guaranteed in my situation that `onchange` will be executed first, then the `change` event which was later defined than the `onchange` event?

EDIT

We can control the order of the events with this prototype:

```
function CustomEventHandler() {
    let events = new Map();
    this.add = (tags, eventKeys, eventFunctions) => {
        let isNew = false;
        for (let tag of tags) {
            if (!events.has(tag)) events.set(tag, new Map());
            let outerItem = events.get(tag);
            for (let eventKey of eventKeys) {
                if (isNew = !outerItem.has(eventKey)) outerItem.set(eventKey, []);
                let innerItem = outerItem.get(eventKey);
                for (let eventFunction of eventFunctions) innerItem.push(eventFunction);
                if (isNew) {
                    tag.addEventListener(eventKey, () => {this.execute(tag, eventKey)});
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    };

    this.execute = (tag, eventKey) => {
        if (events.has(tag)) {
            let outerItem = events.get(tag);
            if (outerItem.has(eventKey)) {
                let innerItem = outerItem.get(eventKey);
                for (let func of innerItem) func(tag, eventKey);
            }
        }
    };

    this.get = () => {return events};
}
```

For example, if we visit https://stackoverflow.com/

and run the prototype code in console and use this prototype as:

```
var ceh = new CustomEventHandler();

var items = document.querySelectorAll(".question-summary.narrow");

ceh.add(items, ["mouseenter"], [function(tag, eventKey) {
    tag.style["background-color"] = "green";
}, function(tag, eventKey) {console.log(eventKey)}
]).add(items, ["mouseleave"], [function(tag, eventKey) {
    tag.style["background-color"] = "white";
}]);
```

then we can see the events being correctly executed in the correct order. We could add custom functionalities, like adding an identifier to a function and be able to remove a function by identifier, or swap their order, but for the sake of simplicity I omitted the implementation of these features. The global scope is used for the sake of simplicity in our case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOM Level 3 (came with HTML5) now orders events in the order they are attached.

Here is the reference to the spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/Overview.html#changes-DOMEvents2to3Changes-flow

> **11.1.1. Changes to DOM Level 2 event flow**
>
> This new specification introduced the following new concepts in the
>   event flow:
>
> - Event listeners are now ordered. In DOM Level 2, the event ordering
>     was unspecified.

Comment: DOM Level 3 Events (which you link to) is still in Working Draft status. And, the passage you are quoting refers to events registered with `.addEventListener()`. This question is really asking about events registered via HTML attributes vs. event properties.

Answer (score 2):

Your question boils down to: *"Will the order of events wired up via HTML attributes vs. the same event wired up with DOM object properties remain consistent over time?"*.

The answer is most-likely, but there's no guarantee. If you want certainty, don't use either technique, use the DOM [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method for event registration. This is what the other answer actually is referring to as far as events now being ordered. When you register events with `.addEventListener()`, for a particular event, you can be assured that the callbacks will be called in the order that they were registered. It doesn't apply to HTML attribute or DOM object property hooked up events.

Comment: Nice answer! I also added some code to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the order is guaranteed for event handlers (too), but not in a very straight forward way.

The specs [have a note](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes:event-handlers-26) stating:

> The event listener registration happens only if the event handler's value is being set to non-null, and the event handler is not already activated. Since listeners are called in the order they were registered, assuming no deactivation occurred, the order of event listeners for a particular event type will always be:
>
> 1. the event listeners registered with addEventListener() before the first time the event handler's value was set to non-null
> 2. then the callback to which it is currently set, if any
> 3. and finally the event listeners registered with addEventListener() after the first time the event handler's value was set to non-null.

This is quite terse and means that only the first setting of an event handler IDL (or attribute parsing) will determine its order.   Any subsequent setting will still have the same order than the first time it was set, unless it's been deactivated in between...

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', e=>console.log('1'));
btn.onclick = e => console.log('2');
btn.addEventListener('click', e=>console.log('3'));

console.log('###test 1###');
btn.click(); //1, 2, 3

btn.addEventListener('click', e=>console.log('4'));
btn.onclick = e => console.log('should be 5 oO');
btn.addEventListener('click', e=>console.log('6'));

console.log('###test 2###');
btn.click(); //1, "should be 5 oO", 3, 4, 6

btn.addEventListener('click', e=>console.log('7'));
btn.onclick = null; // deactivate
btn.onclick = e => console.log('8 oO');
btn.addEventListener('click', e=>console.log('9'));

console.log('###test 4###');
btn.click(); //1, 3, 4, 6, 7, "8 oO", 9
```

```html
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

But beware, this is just the specs standing point, we know all implementations don't always follow the specs.